# Get variable from database table column into input field based selected option from option field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have succesfully retrieved two columns from my table and displayed the result as options in a select tag, in my form.

The problem is I cannot display the data from a third column into an input field, which is also in the form, based on the selected option.

There is no issue with the database connection or retrieving the data for the options in the select tag.

Any help would be appreciated. The relevant code is below.

```
     <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bottommargin-sm">
      <label for="">Choose currency</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

        <option value="">Choose currency...</option>

        <?php

        // Including DB connection file
        include_once "config/config.php";

        // Retrieving all columns from currency table
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM currency_test");

        // Loop printing options with country and currrency for all rows in currency table
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

          print "<option>";

          echo $row['country'] . " - " . $row['currency'];

          print "</option>";

        }

        // Closing DB connection
        mysqli_close($con);

        ?>

      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-12 bottommargin-sm">
      <label for="">Currency rate</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['buy_rate'] ?>" readonly>
    </div>
```

**Additional Edit**

I am now using the following code, still without any luck:

```
     <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bottommargin-sm">
      <label for="">Choose currency/label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

        <option value="default">Choose currency...</option>

        <?php

        // Including DB connection file
        include_once "config/config.php";

        // Retrieving all columns from currency table
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM currency_test");

        // Loop printing country, currrency, buy_rate and sell_rate for all rows in currency table
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

          echo "<option value=".$row['currency']."> ".$row['country']. " - " .$row['currency']." </option>";

        }

        ?>

      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-12 bottommargin-sm">
      <label for="">Currency rate</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['buy_rate'] ?>" readonly>
    </div>

    <?php

    // Closing DB connection
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you closed the connection too soon, so your last input at the bottom won't show you anything.

Comment: And the input could only contain the last row `buy_rate` value.

Comment: And another! Is the `buy_rate` the same for ALL the rows in the result set?

Comment: woudn't $row be null/false after the while?

Comment: Voting this as a simple typographical error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I have now moved the closing of the connection to later in the document, but still no effect.

Comment: @ZakiHussain can you update/edit your question so that it contains what you're using now and please mark it as an additional edit? Also, the `$row` for that last input is outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, but if I put the last $row inside the loop, the options will contain that column.

Comment: store the (first, last, any??) value of `$row['buy_rate']` in a seperate variable and use that in your input. _If you want_ the buy_rate to be updated when you select another currency you'll need javascript (or a form with another db query only for that.).

Comment: Because the last thing your while loop does is notice that the resultset has been fully consumed (which terminates the while loop) in doing this it sets `$row` to NULL. So using `$row` after the while  loop, it will not contain anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, you have a result SET in your while-loop above, but you want the input field only to contain a single value: the buy-rate of the selected currency. If I guessed right and this is what you want, this will not work like this.

If you want to test it and just retrieve only a single value in your while-loop, also your input field gets filled with the correct buy-rate.

You can do it with or without JavaScript, but you need a second statement to retrieve the buyrate you desire.

Further security suggestions: You should not use the include directives without __ DIR __ . Neither you should use "SELECT * ...". Better it is to name all the fields you want to retrieve.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you. How does including with DIR work?

Comment: If you have a file to include and want to use the absolute path, use __ DIR __ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'yourFile.php': Then you get the absolute path. __ DIR __ is one of the "magic constants"

Answer (score -1):

You will have to have a statement for that selection. (Hint: Also in the  tag you will have to have a value attribute set) Also your select needs a name if you use a submit button..

Now when you submit the form you can query the database and show the correct record.

If you dont want to use a submit button and have the value in the textfield change by selection, you will need javascript.

Answer (score -2):

So what I see :

1) No name in select tag

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
```

There is no name attribute. So after posting the form, the server doesn't know the name of the variable.

2) No value

```
print "<option>";
```

You don't supply a value. So your server doesn't know the value (the user selected) after posting the form.

This is the proper way for a select tag : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp